# Enabling nomodeset in Ubuntu and Arch multiboot

Tags: grub2

I have an ubuntu and archlinux multiboot system. The grub is installed by the ubuntu system. So, it is grub 2. I want to set the nomodeset for the arch boot. I am unable to set it permanently.

I  cannot edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg as it is autogenerated

Editing /etc/default/grub not working as well (as it changes only the Ubuntu setting)

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK the menu-entry for other os in grub is written through `os-prober` if you don't have custom menu entry. You may try to edit `30_os-prober` file in `/etc/grub.d/` from line 229.

Answer (score 1):

The solution requires a config file edit to /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober. Be sure to back up the original file, first!

You need to find the line that says, "linux ${LKERNEL} ${LPARAMS}" and change it to say "linux ${LKERNEL} ${LPARAMS} nomodeset".

Then run update-grub and try it out.

Tim

Answer (score -1):

I red through the Ubuntu posting here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-default.2BAC8-grub_.28file.29

I cannot find any reference to modding the GRUB file to incorporate what you want to do.

The only thing you might try is the grub-customizer. It has additional settings and can do custom entries.

Comment: The question seems to be how to set an option for the Arch boot, given that modifying Grub 2 will only modify the Ubuntu boot.  Your answer just tells him how to check his version of Grub...which he already knows.

Comment: I thought it was purposed as a question. "So, it is GRUB 2". I was given the impression that you were unsure.